# How to make a single module and resolve the dependency in android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I have an aosp code copy, and do a full build some days ago,
recently I sync the code to the latest, and try to modify some code in Contacts module, and try to build it with:

```
mmm packages/apps/Contacts
```

there is an error:

```
1 error during configuration. Try --help-properties for help.
  Property 'jack.library.import' (in Options): element #1: The version of the library file 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-test_intermediates/classes.jack' is not supported anymore. Library version: 3.4 - Current version: 3.5 - Minimum compatible version: 3.5
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:84: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I search android-support-test in opengrok, and find android-support-test in prebuilts/misc/common/android-support-test
then I do:

> mmm prebuilts/misc/common/android-support-test/

still error:

```
1 error during configuration. Try --help-properties for help.
  Property 'jack.classpath': element #1: The version of the library file 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v23_intermediates/classes.jack' is not supported anymore. Library version: 3.4 - Current version: 3.5 - Minimum compatible version: 3.5
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:84: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

but I can't find sdk_23 module in opengrok.

then I delete

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-test_intermediates/classes.jack
```

and do

```
make android-support-test
```

It doesn't rebuild the module.

So, how can I solve the dependency when using "mmm" building a module?

Comment: Have you tried "mma Contacts" from root repo directory?

Comment: yes ,I've tried this, but some dependency error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Jack keeps on not liking your prebuilt material (`/out` dir), is it from an entire different Android version?

I would suggest to do `make clean` OR just delete all /out/ directory from root repo.

Then do `mma Contacts` from root repo directory.

For further info on mm, mmm, mma, etc. Check build/envsetup.sh:

```
Invoke ". build/envsetup.sh" from your shell to add the following functions to your environment:
   lunch:   lunch <product_name>-<build_variant>
   tapas:   tapas [<App1> <App2> ...] [arm|x86|mips|armv5] [eng|userdebug|user]
   croot:   Changes directory to the top of the tree.
   m:       Makes from the top of the tree.
   mm:      Builds all of the modules in the current directory, but not their dependencies.
   mmm:     Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, but not their dependencies.
            To limit the modules being built use the syntax: mmm dir/:target1,target2.
   mma:     Builds all of the modules in the current directory, and their dependencies.
   mmma:    Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories, and their dependencies.
   cgrep:   Greps on all local C/C++ files.
   jgrep:   Greps on all local Java files.
   resgrep: Greps on all local res/*.xml files.
   godir:   Go to the directory containing a file.
```